# How to make error message?

Tags: bash

When I execute bash script in eclipse the error output is written in red text. I have some behaviour in my code that is letting "user" know that error has occurred, how to make in error look like error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used eclipse for a while, but if I remember correctly, the console view uses red color for stderr.

If you want to execute your application and get red color for error messages, then print them to stderr instead of stdout.

Comment: how to do it in bash? i'm running bash script from eclipse (in eclipse console)

Comment: You can redirect `stdout` to `stderr` in `echo` like this: `echo "error message here" 1>&2`. For more information, you can refer to the [all about redirection](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html) article.